# Meaning of 'Почем Знать?'

Tags: значения, фраза

Что означает 'почем знать?' Это нечто вроде 'who knows?'

Answer (score 4):

*«почем»* is a colloquial word, literally meaning "what for?".

The phrase «*а мне почем знать?*» means "*why would I know?*" or "*how can I know it?*"